# When I click on the Cardview how to keep it in its ON state with the same color until I click it OFF?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, cardview

I have a card view with on-click listener on it. As I click on it the color of card view get change which means it is ON. But as I move on any another activity the color of card view get change. I do not want that color to get change. Help me out.
Code of card view...

```
    private void setToggleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {

    final CardView bulb=(CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(0);

    bulb.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"));

    bulb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(bulb.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor()!=Color.parseColor("#FFD100"))
                {
                    bulb.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD100"));

                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("BULB");
                    myRef.setValue("1");
                }
                else
                {
                    bulb.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"));

                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("BULB");
                    myRef.setValue("0");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use SharedPreferences to save your card status.

Comment: As you go to another activity and come back again on the `card view activity` the activity gets created again and loads from the start. So here u have to maintain the state with `SharedPrefernce` and add the check before setting the color to the card view.

Comment: Do you have any code for it?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


    String color = sharedPreferences.getString("MY_KEY", "#fcfcfc");//#fcfcfc is defualt value!
     bulb.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

     bulb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


     if (bulb.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() != Color.parseColor("#fcfcfc")) {
                            bulb.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fcfcfc"));
                            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("MY_KEY", "#fcfcfc").apply();

                            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("BULB");
                            myRef.setValue("1");
                        } else {
                            bulb.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"));
                            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("MY_KEY", "#404040").apply();

                            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("BULB");
                            myRef.setValue("0");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Getting an error at context and the error is "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference"